# Reindex data in new cluster should update with latest time stamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Recently I have reindexed the data from one elastic cluster to another which is of latest version. But the data present in previous cluster was older data, Now I need this data in new cluster with latest time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script in the reindex api

Something like that should work

```
POST _reindex
 {
   "source": {
     "index": "test"
   }, 
   "dest": {
     "index": "test2"
   }, 
   "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
          ctx._source['@timestamp'] = new Date().getTime();
            """
   }
 }
```

Comment: Abhi, I saw your comment. if you are not able to see the @timestamp please ensure your are looking at the reindexed index. Be sure also that the reindex query was executed without any error on your side

Comment: @abhi, did you manage to reindex ? if so, please don't forget to validate it